# How to set "xpack.security.enrollment.enabled" to "true for elasticsearch in Docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

This is how I start elasticsearch with Kibana in "Docker for Windows":

```
docker network create --driver bridge elastic

docker run -p 127.0.0.1:9200:9200 -p 127.0.0.1:9300:9300 --name elasticsearch -v elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e ELASTIC_USER=Andreas -e ELASTIC_PASSWORD=Hirsebrei docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.5.2

docker run --name kib-01 -p 5601:5601 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.5.3
```

This all runs fine and I can open the Kibana pagein the browser which requests an enrollment token.
I use the following from a command line to generate the enrollment token:

```
docker exec -it elasticsearch /bin/sh
```

then in the shell I do this:

```
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/

./elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token --scope kibana
```

which results in the following error message:

```
ERROR: [xpack.security.enrollment.enabled] must be set to `true` to create an enrollment token
```

Now I am lost.

Can someone please help me out and explain to me how to set `[xpack.security.enrollment.enabled]` to `true`?

Comment: Can you do it via environment variable?
```-e xpack.security.enabled=true```
At least it looks like these settings can be passed as environment variables: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#_prepare_the_environment

Comment: Or maybe even better description: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-configuration-methods

Comment: @MikeMozhaev This did help.  But now I get the following error:

```ERROR: Unable to create an enrollment token. Elasticsearch node HTTP layer SSL configuration is not configured with a keystore```

Comment: I don't have a specific advice. There is a section about keystore, maybe you'll find an answer there: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-keystore-bind-mount
Seems like you could mount a volume and then create a store as described in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/elasticsearch-keystore.html

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and after digging deep into the problem I post my considerations here and at the footer the link to the official docs.

### docker vs docker compose

I you launch the `docker run` you MUST follow what is written in official elastic docs. In particular the flag `-it` create a pseudo console necessary to auto-generate the password and enrollment token

If you launch the container with `docker-compose.yml` the Auto-generated password and enrollment will NOT be generated, (see the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/85047#issuecomment-1070327178))
and is necessary to generate manually with the following commands:

```
docker exec -ti elastic_container_name /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic
docker exec -ti elastic_container_name /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s kibana
```

If you want a compose file with full setup you must use the official docker-compose file from elastic
[docs here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-compose-file) [github here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/main/docs/reference/setup/install/docker).

If you want a single node, **remove EVERYTHINGS** regarding node2 and node3

### Security

I have noticed (but maybe wrong) that if you use ANY of the security env variables i.e. `ELASTIC_PASSWORD` or event setting the `xpack.security.enabled=true` you must set ALL security by hand (certificates, password, and so on).

If you try to *remove* security with `xpack.security.enabled=false` kibana doesn't work correctly.

### Single node for dev purpose

I post here my solution

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  node01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.8.0
    networks:
      - net1
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    container_name: es-node01
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.8.0
    networks:
      - net1
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    container_name: kib-01
    depends_on: 
      - node01
networks:
  net1:
```

start with `docker compose up -d` and wait until all is started.

launch this command to generate (reset) the *elastic* user password
`docker exec -ti es-node01 /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic`

launch this command to generate the enrollment token
`docker exec -ti es-node01 /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s kibana`

Open in the browser `http://localhost:5601/` this will popup the window to insert the enrollment token, then ask for the verification code, open the logs on kibana container and read the code.

When finished it asks for a username and password, insert *elastic* and the password generated above.

[Elastic with Docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html)